# Forecasting with extrenal regressors in R using RUGARCH

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, garch

I am struggling to find the solution of my problem, I want to model the volatility of the DAX index using some explanatory variables to do so. I am using the rugarch packed and I model the series has been a e-garch type. The problem is in the forecast. I want to forecast 100 observation and the compare it to the original series, the problem is that the forecast is a straight line that does not make any sense.

```
daxspec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                            submodel = NULL, external.regressors = dax2, variance.targeting = FALSE), 
                      mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1), external.regressors = NULL, distribution.model = "std"))

daxgarch3 <- ugarchfit(spec=daxspec,data=dax$volatility, out.sample = 100)

daxgarch3

daxfor=ugarchforecast(daxgarch3, data = NULL, n.ahead = 100, n.roll
                        = 0, out.sample = 100, external.forecasts = list(mregfor=NULL, vregfor=dax2))

plot(fitted(daxfor), type="l")
```

this is my code till now.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: You didn't post your data so there's no way to know, but a priori there is nothing wrong with the forecast being a straight line. What are the parameter estimates? Are you aware that your external regressors are in the variance equation, not the mean equation? Is the data you pass to `ugarchfit` the DAX returns, or some estimate of DAX volatility as the variable is named?